# Record stream with avconv stops prematurley

Tags: avconv

I am trying to simply record a IP camera stream to my harddrive on Ubuntu Linaro. It works very well for 4 seconds then stops. There are no errors and playback is perfect. It seems like it is doing it intentionally. However I cannot for the life see where this file size  is set. It stops after approx 280k. If I lower the stream size it just records for longer but always stops when the file is roughly 280k. If I reduce the filesize with the -fs options and can force it smaller but any value over the 280k leaves the file at 280k. Here is my output :

```
avconv -y -i 'rtsp://192.168.0.100:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&streamprofile=Quality' -benchmark -loglevel debug -c copy test.mpg
```

Produces :

```
avconv version 0.8-4:0.8-1ubuntu1linaro1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 26 2012 15:06:17 with gcc 4.6.1
  configuration: --extra-version='4:0.8-1ubuntu1linaro1' --arch=arm --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libfreetype --extra-cflags='-marm -fPIC -DPIC' --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/neon/vfp --extra-cflags='-mfpu=neon -fPIC -DPIC' --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil    51. 21. 0 / 51. 21. 0
  libavcodec   53. 34. 0 / 53. 34. 0
  libavformat  53. 20. 0 / 53. 20. 0
  libavdevice  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
  libavfilter   2. 15. 0 /  2. 15. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
[rtsp @ 0x26aa0] SDP:
v=0
o=- 1343234035552520 1343234035552520 IN IP4 192.168.0.100
s=Media Presentation
e=NONE
b=AS:50000
t=0 0
a=control:rtsp://192.168.0.100:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&streamprofile=Quality
a=range:npt=0.000000-
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50000
a=framerate:30.0
a=transform:1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1
a=control:rtsp://192.168.0.100:554/axis-media/media.amp/trackID=1?videocodec=h264&streamprofile=Quality
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; profile-level-id=420029; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAKeKQCgDLYC3AQEBpB4kRUA==,aM48gA==

[rtsp @ 0x26aa0] video codec set to: h264
[NULL @ 0x2a800] RTP Packetization Mode: 1
[NULL @ 0x2a800] RTP Profile IDC: 42 Profile IOP: 0 Level: 29
[NULL @ 0x2a800] Extradata set to 0x2ad80 (size: 29)!hello state=0
[h264 @ 0x2a800] err{or,}_recognition separate: 1; 1
[h264 @ 0x2a800] err{or,}_recognition combined: 1; 1
[h264 @ 0x2a800] Unsupported bit depth: 0
[rtsp @ 0x26aa0] All info found
[rtsp @ 0x26aa0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.0.100:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&streamprofile=Quality':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.039989, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0, 22, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p, 1280x800 [PAR 1:1 DAR 8:5], 1/180000, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[mpeg @ 0x2fac0] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail
Output #0, mpeg, to 'test.mpg':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf53.20.0
    Stream #0.0, 0, 1/90000: Video: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, yuvj420p, 1280x800 [PAR 1:1 DAR 8:5], 1/90000, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
Received BYE for stream 0 (1/1)=     208kB time=1.36 bitrate=1252.6kbits/s    
frame=   49 fps= 49 q=-1.0 Lsize=     286kB time=1.88 bitrate=1245.9kbits/s    
video:283kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.902341%
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like the stream may be stopping you. `avconv` says "Received BYE for stream 0" near the end. Is there any chance the stream you are trying to capture is cutting off after a certain amount of data?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command:

```
avconv -rtsp_transport tcp -i
```

This works for me.

Comment: OP really should mark this one as the answer, as this resolved my problem